# phonegap visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

[image]I am creating 'Blank App(Apache Cordova)' in visual studio 2015. When i run this app in 'Google Android Emulator', the errors comes like the attached image. Please help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I guess you forgot to attach the error message?

Comment: Now, i have attached.